# how to find maximum date in multidimensional array based on another key in php?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

if i having an array like this,how to filter an array

```
Array
(
[Response] => 1
[Result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P64312044DEMO
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 14/09/2010
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P87841128
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 28/09/2011
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => Q29074986
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 26/09/2012
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => Q29408317
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 30/09/2013
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => G74789710
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 30/09/2016
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => G73849945
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 28/09/2017
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => H36988574
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 29/09/2018
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P26914598
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 26/08/2008
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P27896539
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 26/08/2008
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P37633229
                [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
                [Event_date] => 02/09/2009
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P26915405
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => -
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P37837226
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => -
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P64308497
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => -
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => P87841185
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => -
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => Q29583176
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => -
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => Q30348593
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => -
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => Q77196582
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => -
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => Q77201333
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => 30/09/2015
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => G52230372
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => 30/09/2016
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => G73246548
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => 28/09/2017
            )

        [20] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => H36208080
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => 29/09/2018
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => H36402733
                [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
                [Event_date] => 29/09/2018
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => S43354968
                [Eform_name] => Form ADT-1
                [Event_date] => 30/09/2015
            )

        [23] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => G72935596
                [Eform_name] => Form ADT-1
                [Event_date] => 29/12/2017
            )

        [24] => Array
            (
                [SRN] => H30204291
                [Eform_name] => Form ADT-1
                [Event_date] => 28/11/2018
            )
         )
      )
```

And i want result like this ,here find maximum date based on key Form ADT-1 ,Form AOC-4 and Form MGT-7 like this

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [SRN] => H36988574
        [Eform_name] => Form MGT-7
        [Event_date] => 29/09/2018
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [SRN] => H36402733
        [Eform_name] => Form AOC-4
        [Event_date] => 29/09/2018
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [SRN] => H30204291
        [Eform_name] => Form ADT-1
        [Event_date] => 28/11/2018
    )

)
```

And i want result like this ,here find maximum date based on key Form ADT-1 ,Form AOC-4 and Form MGT-7 like this.Here find maximum date based on Eform_name column .

And i want result like this ,here find maximum date based on key Form ADT-1 ,Form AOC-4 and Form MGT-7 like this.Here find maximum date based on Eform_name column .

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array and use strtotime to parse the date as Unix time.
If it's a higher number then it's a newer date, replace the value in $result array.
I create an associative array to make it easier.
If you don't want or need the associative then you can add `$result = array_values($result);` after the loop.

```
foreach($arr['Result'] as $a){
    $unix = strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$a['Event_date']));
    if(!isset($result[$a['Eform_name']])){
        $result[$a['Eform_name']] = $a;
    }else{
        if($unix > strtotime(str_replace("/","-", $result[$a['Eform_name']]['Event_date']))){
             $result[$a['Eform_name']] = $a;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["Form MGT-7"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["SRN"]=>
    string(9) "H36988574"
    ["Eform_name"]=>
    string(10) "Form MGT-7"
    ["Event_date"]=>
    string(10) "29/09/2018"
  }
  ["Form AOC-4"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["SRN"]=>
    string(9) "H36208080"
    ["Eform_name"]=>
    string(10) "Form AOC-4"
    ["Event_date"]=>
    string(10) "29/09/2018"
  }
  ["Form ADT-1"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["SRN"]=>
    string(9) "H30204291"
    ["Eform_name"]=>
    string(10) "Form ADT-1"
    ["Event_date"]=>
    string(10) "28/11/2018"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/DKcR8